# Ensure that the current user has required permissions to access the temporary location

Tags: windows, oracle, client, server, oracle12c

Error messsage: Ensure that the current user has required permissions to access the temporary location.

System: Windows 2012 32 bit
Application: Oracle 12c Client 32 bit

Additional Information: 
 - Framework setup check failed on all the nodes
 - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
 - Action: User Action Not Available
Summary of the failed nodes
xxx
 - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "xxx"
 - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
 - Action: User Action Not Available

Please advise
Driver123

Answer (score 0):

It solved now.

If the server no internet connection, I received this error message. When I acceess the internet, It works

Best
Drivers123